# Where can I find my Facebook application id and secret key?

Tags: facebook

In my Facebook account, where can I find these application IDs, secret key, all?

Answer (score 96):

You should use the [Developer App](http://www.facebook.com/developers/).

On the right is a section titled "My Applications" from which you can select an application to see its information.

You can also go straight [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) as well, which will list your apps on the left.

Comment: That url asks for a password, my normal account password doesn't work. Do you have to sign up for something else?

Comment: Nevermind it seems chrome was having trouble getting past that page, in Firefox the page actualy works when you input your password.

Comment: **One important thing...** You have to be logged into your **personal account** not business account when following these directions.

Comment: You must be logged in as an administrator of the app for this to work.

Answer (score 75):

From 2018:

Go to `Settings -> Basic -> App Secret` (type your password and you're ready to go).

Comment: The full path is: (1) https://developers.facebook.com/ (2) My Apps > [select your app] (3) on the left underneath Dashboard, click on Settings (4) and then what @vljs said

Answer (score 15):

I had a hard time finding where it is so here the image depicting it in 2019.
[image: the location of app secret and app id in 2019.]

Answer (score 7):

Just simply click on your app name and look on your right, you app id should be there

For your app secret, u have to click **show**.

[image]

Hope that helps !

Comment: After Use this App Id my application i am getting error like "You are not logged in".

Comment: This solution is outdated.

Comment: Yes facebook have new design please update your answer too

Answer (score 4):

Make a Facebook app with these simple steps I have written below:

1. Go to Developer tab and click on it.
2. Then go to Website Option.
3. Enter the app name which you have want.
4. Click on Create Facebook App.
5. After this you have to choose category, you can choose App for Pages.
6. Your AppId and Appkey is created automatically. The AppSecretKey is obfuscated. You can click on the show button to see your AppId and AppSecurityKey.

Comment: i did all this and got app id, but still i am not able to use it

Comment: This solution is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Peter's post is pretty much spot on, but if you want to learn how to navigate to it yourself here are the instructions:

On the left hand menu, you need to click "more", then you'll see "Developer", click on it. Afterwards you'll be presented with a page where your apps are listed under "My Applications" click on "See my applications". You can find all your API Key, secrets, and IDs there.

Answer (score 1):

It is under Account -> Application Settings, click on your application's profile, then go to Edit Application.

Comment: in the above steps and not find any edit applicaiton option,,,

Comment: huh ? it was there for my created apps. for every apps listed in application settings, the should be 2 links, Edit Settings and Profile, the Edit Application is after you clicked on Profile link, unless you do not have the rights to edit the app

Comment: gOT ERROR 
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in E:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-71d9a52\src\facebook.php on line 511

Comment: i see.. you're using the API right ? you need to add these CURL options in facebook.php

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

its under public static $CURL_OPTS... find it

Comment: i added the that snippet
 '  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-2.0',
 
  );'

but still i has error


Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in E:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-71d9a52\src\facebook.php on line 511

Comment: not sure which version you are using, but i have 2 versions, 2.0.4 and 2.0.5 both, no need to add the options, its already there, you just need to add 1 extra line. so here is mine :

public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-2.0',
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
  );

Comment: @Puaka setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` is more of a bandaid than an actual solution.  What you really need to do is tell curl where your crt file is located. `Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt'`

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard -> [your app] -> [View Details] -> Settings -> Basic

[source](https://theonetechnologies.com/blog/post/how-to-get-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)

Answer (score 0):

url https://developers.facebook.com/apps
here you'll see all apps listed after that go to Settings then click on Basic
then App Secret input then click on show now you can see your app secert key.