# What is $wgFbSecret for wiki integration?

Tags: facebook, mediawiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find my Facebook application id and secret key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)

What is `$wgFbSecret` for the Facebook Mediawiki extension?  It can't be my password, since the `$wgFbSecret` token sits in the publicly viewable `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: See also [Where can I find my Facebook application secret key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203649/1048572)

Comment: Anyway, [`LocalSettings.php` should not be publicly viewable](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php#Security). If you want to be really sure, [move the sensitive information to a file outside your webserver directories](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Security#Move_sensitive_information) and `include()` that file from `LocalSettings.php`.  Having a line like `RewriteRule ^w/.*Settings\.php - [F,L]` in your `.htaccess` file isn't a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark here - no experience at all with `mediawiki`. I think this parameter is the application secret. You can get this value from the settings of your application -

[image]