# I am new to Facebook SDK with iOS. I want to send invitation to friends on Facebook and find friend list

Tags: ios, facebook

1. When we write a code for friend the the following error arrive
2. The code is given bellow
3. View **control.h** file

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <FBFriendPickerDelegate> - (IBAction)FBFriend:(id)sender;

   @end
   ```
4. View **control.m** file

   ```
   -(IBAction)FBFriend:(id)sender {
       FBFriendPickerViewController* vc=[[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc]init];
       [vc loadData];
       [vc presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES
       handler:^(FBViewController*sender, BOOL donePressed) {
           if (donePressed) {
               NSLog(@"success!");
           }
       }];
   }
   ```
5. When we run the code the the following error arive
6. > Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'`

Comment: the error message says clearly, you need to provide the FacebookAppID, probably this link leads you to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key

Answer (score 0):

first you have create app id for your  app in facebook.developers page,you can go for following link for more details [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Comment: i have also created an App id on developer.facebook.com and conf. that  id in our project on plist file by adding new row

Answer (score 0):

In App, User first needs to login before send invitation to friends on Facebook and find friend list.

Please find the following link in Facebook docs about login https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

Please let me know if still you have any questions.

Comment: sir i m already login and my simple social framework work properly