# Facebook integration in Android. What is the application id?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm not a facebook developer, i'm a newby in android/facebook integration.

I'm trying to share images with text, for some [known reasons/bugs](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) facebook won't let the share intent ACTION_SEND to work correctly, not filling extra fields like EXTRA_TEXT, EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, EXTRA_SUBJECT.

As a workaround, i'm trying to use [FacebookImageShareIntent](https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent) but somewhere it requires the `application ID`.

What is it?
Why should i need it in my android app?
Should i create a new application in [developers.facebook.com/apps/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)? To do what?
When i access that page i see a "loginF" application that has an App ID, who created it? Should i use this App ID?

I tried googling for a while, but still don't understand...

Please, someone clarify, thanx

Comment: It is the which will get created when you create app under 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key

Comment: @RIT i don't think it's a duplicate... and why should i use it in my android app? what is the benefit of a facebook application to my app?

Comment: Actually app id is unique for every facebook integration app. Because sometimes you come across situation where facebook can't allow more user to use same app id. So that time you can allow your app users to create separate app id for logging in. So simply facebook app id is used for logging in purpose.

Comment: I'll explain you, if you still want to know more app id.

Comment: @RIT thanx. I'm starting undertanding now... I just need to let users share images with text, is it enough to use my loginF app id for this?

Comment: You always ask only one question on one thread to get more attention to your question. If my above comment is helpful then you should upvote it. This is stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need APP ID to use Facebook APIs. Use [Facebook Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) tutorial to get your APP ID.

Comment: Thanx, but i don't understand why. It seems to be optional, then what's its goal?

Comment: It's not optional, it's required. Use Getting Started tutorial to get it.

Comment: http://goo.gl/go6bp3 states: "Providing a Facebook Application ID for use with the Social Media Sharing feature is recommended, but optional", it's first result googling "facebook applicationid"... Getting started tutorial is making me crazy, i find very hard to make things to work, maybe a bad eclipse setup...

Comment: It's optional only for **use with the Social Media Sharing feature**