# Facebook Login Page not displayed, only a white page with the word "Success"

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to open a *Facebook login page* on my `Winform` application.

```
private const string AppId = "MY_APP_ID";
private Uri loginUrl;
private const string extendedPermissions = "user_about_me,publish_stream,offline_acccess";
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login();
}

private void Login()
{
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.client_id = AppId;
    parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    parameters.response_type = "token";
    parameters.display = "popup";
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
        parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

On the first attempt, my `webBrowser1` only displayed a warning message that I am not authenticated to allow the page. I Googled the issue and read that I should change the settings of my app (advanced) and enabled the options

- Native or desktop app?
- Is App Secret embedded in the client?

After this, instead of the warning I am receiving a blank page with the word "Success" and after a second or two a red warning is added that reminds me not to share this URL anywhere else and treat it as a password.
[image]

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Is it because by default cookies are disabled in `webBrowser` control? If so, how can I enable them?

Comment: The browser used in c sharp application is internet explorer. So if you want to enable cookies or whatever changes you make in internet explorer, that will reflect in your application

Comment: FYI: The “Success” comes from `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`, it is the only content of that page. And you get to see it, because you were already logged in to the app previously – this is what is _supposed to happen_ in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The login screened was displayed correctly when I changed my `extendedPermissions` to only

```
"user_about_me"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure wether you did this on purpose or never edited it in the first place but I see you've left `private const string AppId = "MY_APP_ID";` the way it is when you copy it from Facebook. You've to link Facebook to your page by putting your own AppID, like `private const string AppId = "012345678";` . If you don't know what your AppID, the best rated answer to this post explains it the best [Post about appID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)

If this isn't the problem, please address your problem in a different way.

Comment: I have my App Id my friend. I just didn't paste it here. In my code, App Id is set to my App Id. You can trust me on that.