# How to resolve facebook ID errorr

Tags: ios, swift, parsefacebookutils

[image]
How to work around this bug, as I looked all I remember and I find no answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

import UIKit
import Parse

// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// import ParseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        // ****************************************************************************
        // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:
        // Parse.setApplicationId("your_application_id", clientKey: "your_client_key")

        Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxxxxxxx",
            clientKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx")

        // iniciar com facebook

        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)



        // If you are using Facebook, uncomment and add your FacebookAppID to your bundle's plist as
        // described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/
        // Uncomment the line inside ParseStartProject-Bridging-Header and the following line here:
        // PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
        // ****************************************************************************

        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var noPushPayload = false;
            if let options = launchOptions {
                noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }

        //
        //  Swift 1.2
        //
        //        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        //            let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        //            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        //            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //        } else {
        //            let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        //        }

        //
        //  Swift 2.0
        //
        //        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        //            let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        //            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
        //            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //        } else {
        //            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        //        }

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Push Notifications
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            if succeeded {
                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
            } else {
                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
            }
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Uncomment this method if you want to use Push Notifications with Background App Refresh
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //     if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
    //         PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    //     }
    // }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Facebook SDK Integration
    //--------------------------------------

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Uncomment this method if you are using Facebook
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    //     return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, session:PFFacebookUtils.session())
    // }


    // resposta do facebook quando ele faz login
    func application(application: UIApplication, openUrl url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clear :

- Edit info plist and a new line with key FacebookAppID, and value your facebook id
- or Use FBSDKSettings.setAppID("your app facebook id")

[Where can I find my Facebook application id and secret key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)