# Facebook login with intel xdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, intel-xdk

Is there any alternative or tutorial that allows me to test the facebook login using the intel XDK environment.

I found this link (I created a facebook app on the facebook developer website):

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/article/facebook-connect-plugin-android-ios

but when I click on the "**Login with facebook**" button, I got a prompt window with my "**APP_ID**", I didn't know what to put on the second field?

Answer (score 0):

App_Id is the facebook application id 
you have to create it from facebook developer

here is the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)