# How to integrate facebook share dialog to my website?

Tags: facebook

The Integration documentation is available in facebook but they haven't given actual code to integrate on our website. Please help me somebody..

When i am using this the button not working

see this in facebook ------->
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650

The Integration documentation is available in facebook but they haven't given actual code to integrate on our website. Please help me somebody..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an app id and then add this script,first thing after the body tag

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : Your-app-id,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

You can get an appid by going to https://developers.facebook.com and creating a new app for your website.

This might be useful : [Where can I find my Facebook application id and secret key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)