# How do I create or find the Facebook App ID and Secret for an existing Organization page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, secret-key, app-id

I am not a coder, just a marketing director trying to obtain the App ID and App Secret for my organizations existing Facebook Page. I need these for a wordpress plug-in to show our Facebook events on our website.

Insight would be super helpful. (Detailed instructions on what to do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find my Facebook application id and secret key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203649/where-can-i-find-my-facebook-application-id-and-secret-key)

Answer (score 0):

Pages do not have an App ID or App Secret, Apps do. You will have to create an App - which is completely unrelated to a Page in general.

This is where you can create an App: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: So then my follow up question would be how should I create an App so that I am able to pull Facebook events from our organization's page?

Comment: by visiting the link in my answer...there is a button for creating apps. you really cannot miss it.